# FFMPEG in Android doesn't create output file.

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am currently using FFMPEG in my Android project for converting a video file to an audio file.

When I execute converting by FFMPEG library, no error occurs. However, the output file is not created in the folder which I already specified.

Here is my code for generating audio file.

```
OnConvertButtonClickListener convertButtonClickListener = new OnConvertButtonClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(int position) {
        Converter.loadFFMpegBinary();
        String cmd = CMD_HEAD + videoItems.get(position).getTitle() + CMD_STRICT;

        String[] fileDir = videoItems.get(position).getTitle().split(File.separator);
        String fileName = fileDir[fileDir.length-1];
        String out_audio_file = FileManager.getHomeDir()+ File.separator+ fileName.substring(0, fileName.length()-3)+"aac";

        Log.d("tag1", out_audio_file);

        cmd = cmd+out_audio_file;
        Log.e("tag1", cmd);
        String[] command = cmd.split(" ");
        Converter.execFFmpegBinary(command);
    }
};
```

This is exeFFmpegBinary method code, and after executing this method, success is displayed in my Log window.

```
public static void execFFmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
    try {

        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {
                Log.d("execFFmpegBinary", "fail");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                Log.d("execFFmpegBinary", "success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                Log.d("execFFmpegBinary", "progress");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d("execFFmpegBinary", "start");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d("execFFmpegBinary", "finish");
            }
        });

    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // do nothing for now
        Log.d("execFFmpegBinary", "Exception");
    }
}
```

Below is an example of my cmd.

```
-version -y -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20180104_031417.mp4 -f aac -ab 192000 -vn /storage/emulated/0/Memento/20180104_031417.aac
```

Anyone knows why my output file doesn't be created?

Answer (score 2):

I have added audio using ffmpeg may be this will help you.

```
class AddAudio {
    private Context context;
    private FFmpeg ffmpeg;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String videoPath;
    private String videoWithoutAudioPath;
    private String output;

    AddAudio(Context context, String soundPath, String videoPath, String videoWithoutAudioPath, ProgressDialog progressDialog, FFmpeg ffmpeg) {
        this.context = context;
        this.videoPath = videoPath;
        this.ffmpeg = ffmpeg;
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        this.videoWithoutAudioPath = videoWithoutAudioPath;
        String currentMilliSecond = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        output = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + "/test/" + currentMilliSecond + ".mp4";
        //String cmd = "-y -i " + videoWithoutAudioPath + " -i " + soundPath + " -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c:a aac -shortest " + output;
        String cmd = "-y -i " + videoWithoutAudioPath + " -i " + soundPath + " -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c:a aac -shortest " + output;


        encodeAudio(cmd);
    }

    private void encodeAudio(String cmd) {
        String[] command = cmd.split(" ");
        if (command.length != 0) {
            execFFmpegBinary(command);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.empty_command_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void execFFmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
        try {
            ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(String s) {
                    Log.e("Failure", s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String s) {
                    Log.e("Success", s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(String s) {
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Adding audio....");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    /**
                     * delete original video since new video is made with sound
                     */
                    if (deleteOriginalVideo() && deleteWorkingFolder(videoWithoutAudioPath)) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Utils.LOCAL_BROADCAST_CODE);
                        notificationIntent.putExtra(Utils.FILE_PATH, output);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(notificationIntent);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean deleteOriginalVideo() {
        boolean success = false;
        File file = new File(videoPath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            success = file.delete();
        }
        return success;
    }

    private boolean deleteWorkingFolder(String deletePath) {
        File file = new File(deletePath);
        File folder = new File(file.getParent());
        if (folder.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : folder.listFiles()) {
                //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
                child.delete();
            }
        }
        return folder.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry , my output file is not created..TT

Comment: Check permission to read write in external disk. Also try using my code just replace the **command** and call it from your onClick it should be working..

Comment: How to do the increasing the merge speed?

Answer (score 1):

Always check the log from `ffmpeg` (assuming your script is working and it is actually being executed). Yours should show an error:

```
Requested output format 'aac' is not a suitable output format
```

Replace `-f aac` with `-f adts`, or omit the `-f` option if the output is a normal file name with the .aac extension.

Alternatively, since your MP4 input most likely already contains AAC audio consider stream copying it instead of re-encoding. To do so remove `-ab 192000` and add `-c:a copy`.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it doesn't work. I have no idea why the output file is not created even though no error message is shown in log.

Comment: In addition, only start, success, and finish messages appear in log. onProgress() callback method seems to be not executed.

Comment: @WongeunCho Then I'm guessing it is a problem with your code and not with the `ffmpeg` command being executed by the code. You have to narrow down and isolate the problem for us to provide more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

(well, I don't have enough karma to post a comment and I'm pretty new to FFmpeg lib)

what I can think of now is always consider giving a **SPACE(" ")** while concatenating strings in commands for this FFmpeg lib...try following

**change:**

cmd = cmd+out_audio_file;

**To: (mark the space between cmd and out_audio_file)**

cmd = cmd+**" "**+out_audio_file;